# Mongoid custom setters / getters and super

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, setter, getter

I'm trying to modify a setter on an attribute Mongoid model, but unlike ActiveRecord, I cannot call super to have Mongoid actually set the attribute, as the model is using `include Mongoid::Document` rather than a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base`.

I want to be able to do something like this.

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document

    embeds_one :email_account

    def email_account=(_email_account)
        ret = super
        puts "email account updated!"
        do_something
        ret
    end
end
```

except, as its not a subclass, yields

`NoMethodError: super: no superclass method`

Ideas?

EDIT:

How would you do a getter, like

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document

    embeds_one :email_address

    def email_address
        super || "myself@gmail.com"
    end
end
```

Comment: you can do it like, `self[:name] = _name.capitalize`

Comment: sorry, its actually with a embeds_one association, where I can't use self[:name] = (edited example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its an embedded document you can do something on the lines of:

```
def doc=(_doc)
  self.build_doc(_doc.attributes)
end
```

I have tried it in console but didn't tried saving and retrieving it back. If parent is a new record save should be trouble-less, otherwise you might have to look into how to call save on embedded document.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion what you're doing doesn't belong to User model at all. I'd create another method in EmailAccount model and hook it with after_save callback.

```
class EmailAccount
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :user

  after_save :do_something

  def do_something
    puts "email account updated!"
    do_actual_something
  end
end
```

Another way is to use observers http://mongoid.org/docs/callbacks/observers.html

Comment: yeah this would be a better way for this specific example, but my actual code is much more complicated and requires setters / getters to work properly.