# Override a Mongoid model's setters and getters

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Is there a way to override a setter or getter for a model in Mongoid?  Something like:

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :num_users, type: Integer, default: 0
  key :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, class_name: "User", inverse_of: :projects

  # This will not work
  def name=(projectname)
    @name = projectname.capitalize
  end
end
```

where the `name` method can be overwritten without using virtual fields?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699503/mongoid-custom-setters-getters-and-super

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
def name=(projectname)
  self[:name] = projectname.capitalize
end
```

Comment: @user923636 you cannot change the "_id" field of a document once created. So if project name gets changed, you will have to delete old document and create a new one with changed name.

Answer (score 24):

better use

```
def name=(projectname)
  super(projectname.capitalize)
end
```

the method

```
self[:name] = projectname.capitalize
```

can be dangerous, cause overloading with it can cause endless recursion

Comment: @GearHead I have also switched to super over timme(it looks better), although still parts of my code use self[:name] notation and haven't faced any recursions till now.

Comment: How could `super` work if there is no super class?
`Mongoid::Document` is included as Module, I'm confused here ...

Comment: @tothemario look at the http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/030-issue-1-method-lookup.html and http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/031-issue-2-method-lookup.html

Comment: @tothemario If a module is included in a class then it acts as a super class.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with needing to override the "user" setter for a belongs_to :user relationship. I came up with this solution for not only this case but for wrapping any method already defined within the same class.

```
class Class  
  def wrap_method(name, &block)
    existing = self.instance_method(name)

    define_method name do |*args|
      instance_exec(*args, existing ? existing.bind(self) : nil, &block)
    end
end
```

This allows you to do the following in your model class:

```
wrap_method :user= do |value, wrapped|
    wrapped.call(value)
    #additional logic here
end
```

Comment: Do not try to reinvent the bicycle. Use alias_method_chain for this.

Comment: thanks for this! Having trouble with relationship setters and getters as well. sandrew's comment had me look into a_m_c's and I learned about Ruby 2.0's Module#prepend. Great solution and really clean - http://dev.af83.com/2012/10/19/ruby-2-0-module-prepend.html