# field vs method ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have this class:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :revenues, :type => Integer, :default => nil
  attr_accessible :revenues
  #now method
  def revenues
   return 1
  end
end
```

Why in console I get `1` instead `nil`?

```
1.9.3-p125 :002 > u.revenues
 => 1
```

Which has priority, the method or the field? How can I created a method with the same features that a field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override model's setters and getters in Mongoid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306472/override-models-setters-and-getters-in-mongoid)

Comment: Duplicate, but note that the current marked answer there isn't the most correct one.  Use the answer which recommends `super`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `field` macro is defined in Mongoid::Document. It is neither a syntatic feature from Ruby nor from Rails.

What's happening with your code is the following:

1. The `field` function creates for you some methods, one of them is called `revenues`.
2. When you create another method called `revenues`, you are in effect overwriting the previously defined method, therefore making it useless.

Short answer: I don't understand a zip about Mongoid, but chances are that your field still exists even after you defined oce again a method named `revenues`. The only drawback is that you cannot access it by calling `myUser.revenues` anymore.

Try to make a test: access your field with the notation `some_user[:revenues]` and see what happen :)

Best regards